# I get an error with the archipack

Tags: add-on, archipack-add-on

Whenever I try to add a window using archipack, I get an error. Before, it was a black screen but I did the render thumbs thing and now it is this.[image]

Answer (score 2):

From archipack issue tracker

I got both archipack and Filmic Blender working together by adding the raw color space and copied directly from the original ..\Blender\2.80\datafiles\colormanagement\config.ocio over into the colorspaces section of the filmic blender config.ocio file, as well as adding the line:

! {name: Raw, colorspace: Raw}
to the displays > sRGB, BT.1886, and Apple Display P3 sections.

Answer (score 1):

The archipack add-on tries to set color space to *Raw* for an [Image Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html#properties) node. The color space entry cannot be found, because you've installed [Filmic Blender](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender). Its custom OCIO configuration doesn't include a color space named *Raw*.

You either have to uninstall Filmic Blender and use the original OCIO configuration or modify Filmic's OCIO configuration to include the *Raw* color space. This could be accomplished by renaming Filmic's *Non-Colour Data* color space, which is equivalent to Blender's *Raw* color space.

Comment: what would you suggest re a patch to addon for the case of no "Raw" colorspace?

Comment: @batFINGER You mean a patch for archipack to not rely on possibly non-existent color spaces? If we assume that the OCIO config may have been modified, we cannot assume that any specific color space exists. I don't think there's a good solution for this. Failing with an explicit error is almost the best approach, since the add-on cannot perform a sensible workaround. Failing silently and just picking whatever color space is available would be bad.

Comment: Was considering something in addon prefs.  Or throw up a choice for user to choose another.

Comment: @batFINGER Assuming that a color space exists for content that should just be treated as `data`, you could set [`node.image.colorspace_settings.is_data = True`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ColorManagedInputColorspaceSettings.html#bpy.types.ColorManagedInputColorspaceSettings.is_data). If such a color space doesn't exist in the OCIO config, then you wouldn't be able to fix it with a user chosen color space either.

Comment: The explicit use of color space names also affects blenderkit and gltf

Comment: Will probably propose a patch for this within the week.

Comment: colorspace_settings.name = Raw and .is_data=True results on screen are not the same.
Why the hell troy's implementation breaks native implementation using Linear Raw instead of Raw ?
It also break blenderGIS

Comment: @RobertGützkow I have had the same issue since I installed Belnder 4.0 but the answer here is too technical for me to follow. Ho do I rename Filmic's Non-Colour Data color space? Where do I find it?

Comment: @RobertGützkow In Blender 4.0 filmic is no longer the default colour space, we now have AgX. What would be the simplest way to resolve Archipack's conflict now in 4.0?

Comment: @Booth The archipack add-on is no longer shipped with Blender since 3.2 I think? I would have to check the current implementation again, not sure if I find the time. The default OCIO config that Blender ships in 4.0 does contain "Raw", so I would've expected it to work. That being said I do not know whether the add-on is still compatible with current versions of Blender.