# Archipack addon error (raw colour space conflict)

Tags: color-management, archipack-add-on

I have the same issue as described in the question below (see link): archipack addon (free community edition) displays an error when trying to create objects. The answers explain the error has to do with Archipack not finding the color space "Raw" because it is now running under a different name. I understand the solution could be to edit the OCIO file and add or rename back the Raw color space.

Unfortunately I'm not comfortable with editing code and therefore my question is: is there a less technical way to resolve Archipack's conflict with colour spaces in Blender 4.x? If changing the OCIO is still the best/only way to go today, could some one please explain which lines to change exactly and how?

I've only had this issue since Blender 4.0, archipack worked fine before that. I didn't install Blender Filmic addon. Original question with answers here:

[I get an error with the archipack](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170579/i-get-an-error-with-the-archipack)

Comment: It looks as if you need version 2+ for Blender 4 but it isn't free. https://blender-archipack.gumroad.com/l/ZRMyP

Comment: @JohnEason I couldn't find any official statement saying that Blender-archipack community edition for blender 3.+ is no longer maintained. Also, I believe it still ships with Blender by default. The issue I'm experiencing is one that others have had years ago already and could resolve. Therefore I believe there must be a way to solve it.

Comment: Archimesh ships with Blender by default. I don't believe that Archipack has ever shipped with it, but I've never actually used it so I may be wrong.

Comment: It seems both of your statements are false. The Archipack (free version) is only available for versions 3.xx (https://blender-archipack.gumroad.com/l/ZUrMf) and the Archipack addon doesn't ship with Blender anymore since at least version 3.6 since it relies on external dependencies which the Blender Foundation forbids in its shipped addons.

Comment: @Gorgious I agree. Archipack was dropped from Blender around Blender 3.0 as far as I can see. Just checking my previous versions, it's there in 2.93 LTS but missing from 3.3 LTS onwards.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, I wasn't aware of these. I couldn't remember installing Archipack so I thought it must have shipped with Blender. However this particular issue seems to have a solution - I'm just not confident enough with code to know where to change what.

Comment: [1] Unfortunately, this "Raw" fix is not a working solution for Blender 4.x. Blender 4 has breaking changes (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API#Breaking_changes). You can fix the add-on by editing the files. For example to fix the 'Raw' error, edit archipack_preset.py, line 299 & change "Raw" to "Non-Color" & restart Blender. You will get 2 more errors in archipack_gl.py, easy to fix (2D_IMAGE => IMAGE & remove dpi for the font call). But the add-on still won't run. It freezes when it tries to render the icons and it's caught in a loop of runtime errors.->[2]

Comment: [2] these kinds of runtime errors (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable) are hard to fix because you need to debug the script and understand what it does and why there is a 'NoneType' and not the expected object. So the only solution I see is to stick with Blender 3.x and wait for an update of the add-on or debug the add-on yourself (good luck ;-) )

Comment: @Blunder thank you for taking the time to check all that. We'll see if the community edition will get updated to 4.x